# How can I have the buttons "Run" and "Open" work again in Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have Internet Explorer 11 on Win 7.

I go to the address : 
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/products/download.html?product=firefox-stub&os=win&lang=fr

The dialog comes. I have the button *Run*. I click it, but it does not work : nothing happens. Usually, this button works. This is a nice feature, this is why I use IE.

**How can I have the button *Run* work again ?**

I have played with the options, to no avail.

*Edits :*

The button *Open* has the same problem [when I request a document](http://www.jtricks.com/download-text).

**How can I have the button *Open* work again ?**

Comment: you have to Run run again.

Comment: is that the same with other executables you download in IE 11 ?

Comment: @TheJoker - I have clicked several times on *Run*. To no avail.

Comment: Well....It's not the end of the world. :P Try with chrome or firefox. @Nicolas Barbulesco

Comment: @rob - The problem occurs also on other sites, with other executable downloads.

Comment: @TheJoker - Neither Firefox nor Chrome has this handy feature. The button *Run* is why I use IE.

Comment: Why so serious?? @Nicolas Barbulesco

Comment: I encounter the same problem with the button *Open* when I request a file, for instance a RTF file.

Answer (score 2):

Check security settings of browser and, if possible, restore it to default.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to security settings of Internet Explorer.

Try putting  https://www.mozilla.org into Trusted Sites Zone.

Open Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options

Go to Security Tab

Select Trusted Sites

Click Site Button

Add website  https://www.mozilla.org and close the bar.

Close IE and Reopen it, now you should be able to run the downloaded program.

> Alternate

Run Internet Explorer in admin mode,

Start > All Programs > Right Click Internet Explorer and select "Run as admin"

Now you can download and run downloaded problem with run button after download.

Let me know if this helped or not.

Comment: I have tried that. That did not help.